# Why does background color refuse to fill entire screen

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Extremely frustrating problem. In the graphical layout view on eclipse it shows the entire screen filled but when I launch it in the emulator only about half the screen is filled. It will fill until right about after the last button. I've been trying to fix this for hours! Ive tried clean project reinstalling eclipse starting the project over.
Thanks!

Here is the XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            style="@style/LoginFormContainer"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f1c40f">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/usernameHint"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in_short" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/orTV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/orText"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/register_button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/action_register" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the Java code that I use to launch this file. Although it is happening on other files as well.

```
package com.keyconsultant.parse.logintutorial;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.keyconsultant.parse.logintutorial.error.UnknownErrorDialogFactory;
import com.keyconsultant.parse.logintutorial.fragment.BaseFragment;
import com.keyconsultant.parse.logintutorial.model.user.UserManager;
import com.keyconsultant.parse.logintutorial.model.user.authenticate.AuthenticateUserErrorEvent;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.squareup.otto.Subscribe;

/**
 * Fragment for logging in. Includes button for loading the Create account view. 
 * 
 * @author Trey Robinson
 *
 */
public class LoginFragment extends BaseFragment {

    public static final String EXTRA_USERNAME = "com.keyconsultant.parse.logintutorial.activity.extra.USERNAME";
    public static final String EXTRA_PASSWORD = "com.keyconsultant.parse.logintutorial.activity.extra.PASSWORD";

    // UI references.
    private EditText mUserNameEditText;
    private EditText mPasswordEditText;

    /**
     * Factory method for creating new fragments
     * @return
     */
    public static LoginFragment newInstance(){
        return new LoginFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
        mUserNameEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.username);

        mPasswordEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.password);
        mPasswordEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                    attemptLogin();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        view.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                attemptLogin();
            }
        });

        view.findViewById(R.id.register_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                createAccount();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            mUserNameEditText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(EXTRA_USERNAME));
            mPasswordEditText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(EXTRA_PASSWORD));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString(EXTRA_USERNAME, mUserNameEditText.getText().toString());
        outState.putString(EXTRA_PASSWORD, mPasswordEditText.getText().toString());
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
     * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
     * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
     */
    public void attemptLogin() {

        clearErrors();

        // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
        String username = mUserNameEditText.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordEditText.getText().toString();

        boolean cancel = false;
        View focusView = null;

        // Check for a valid password.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            mPasswordEditText.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = mPasswordEditText;
            cancel = true;
        } else if (password.length() < 4) {
            mPasswordEditText.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
            focusView =mPasswordEditText;
            cancel = true;
        }

        // Check for a valid email address.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
            mUserNameEditText.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = mUserNameEditText;
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (cancel) {
            // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
            // form field with an error.
            focusView.requestFocus();
        } else {
            // perform the user login attempt.
            UserManager.getInstance().authenticate(username.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()), password);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Load the create account view. 
     */
    private void createAccount(){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId(), CreateAccountFragment.newInstance());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Remove all edit text errors
     */
    private void clearErrors(){
        mUserNameEditText.setError(null);
        mPasswordEditText.setError(null);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onSignInError(AuthenticateUserErrorEvent event){
        clearErrors();
        switch (event.getErrorCode()) {
        case ParseException.OBJECT_NOT_FOUND:
            mPasswordEditText.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordEditText.requestFocus();
            break;
        default:
            UnknownErrorDialogFactory.createUnknownErrorDialog(this.getActivity()).show();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide definition of LoginFormContainer style, as well as the fragment transaction that adds LoginFragment to container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you are missing android:layout_width="match_parent" for your top-most view container.

Hope this helps.

Comment: layout_width is in the style. It does make a difference if I add it. I ve tried